# GUI Application Resolution from Text Mode OS

Tags: resolution, text-mode

I'm trying to turn a computer into a Linux thin client via Ubuntu. I have a Dell OptiPlex 755 loaded with Ubuntu 14.04 installed and fully patched. I've configured the OS to run in text mode and automatically launch the VMWare Horizon's client, which works.

The issue is that when the Horizon client launches, its resolution is only 1/4 of the screen. I've played with the resolution settings in grub which appears to modify the text environment but not the application environment for Horizon's.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to increase the resolution for a GUI application launch from text mode so it's full screen.

Thanks!